# EmguCV Tesseract application deployment and distribution

Tags: c#, deployment, ocr, tesseract, emgucv

I am using Tesseract OCR in EmguCV. I have developed one simple C# application and now I want to deploy/distribute it.

The problem I see is that it requires me to have x86 folder of OpenCV dlls in the bin folder in order to run the application. This folder is about 381 MBs. Do I need to include this folder while giving the application to someone else. Or is there any other way to elegantly give my application to be used by end user.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pack whole of dll things.
If you include "opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp" in your code, you just need opencv_highgui249.dll file.

Comment: I am not sure what is "opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp" file. I do not have such file included in my project. The assemblies included are Emgu.CV, Emgu.CV.OCR, etc. but I think these files need OpenCV dlls as their dependency.